# Creating alias from java class file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've a little simple question, I don't know if is this possible. But I want create an alias of Java class files.

```
public String viewer() {
     return viewPagerAdapter.class;
}
...
viewer.addFragment(...);
```

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "alias"? Did you want to return the fully qualified name of the `viewPagerAdapter` class? If so, use `viewPagerAdapter.class.getName()`.

Comment: *FYI:* Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, so it should be `ViewPagerAdapter`

Comment: I have a static string inside **ViewPagerAdapter.java**, and I cannot access it using `viewer().myStaticString = (something);`. Do you know why it's happening?

Comment: I want access the same file but with different name, like a shortcut

Comment: Because `viewer()` returns a `String`, not a `ViewPagerAdapter`.

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Don't be lazy and use the full class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't support aliases for class names.

If I understand question correctly, you have a class like this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter {
    public static String myStaticString = "Foo";
}
```

and you have another class where you want to use that string without having to use the "long" name `ViewPagerAdapter`.

There are many ways to accomplish something like that:

```
// Using static import
import static ViewPagerAdapter.myStaticString;
class X {
    void x() {
        String x = myStaticString;
    }
}
```

```
// Copying the value (only use if value is a constant, i.e. final)
class X {
    static String myStaticString = ViewPagerAdapter.myStaticString;
    void x() {
        String x = myStaticString;
    }
}
```

```
// Subclassing (not recommended)
class X {
    static class Viewer extends ViewPagerAdapter {}
    void x() {
        String x = Viewer.myStaticString;
    }
}
```